# Ubuntu installer mode options

Tags: grub2, windows-7

During installation from a bootable USB, Ubuntu installer does not present the option of "installing alongside" Windows 7, but only "erase HD completely" or "Do something else".
I am concerned that this is an indication that if I go ahead with a manual partition of the disk, I may have problems dual booting into Windows 7 - grub may not recognize W7 OS.

Answer (score 0):

Don't choose "Erase HD completely" (it will delete your Windows).

The problem here is that Ubuntu does not detect your Windows.

Please indicate your [Boot-Info URL](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info) if you want further advice.